# Monitor shows discoloration at random when plugging it in

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two monitors where one is always dimmer and less saturated, I thought it was just difference in the monitor itself but after plugging and unplugging them (to tests ports and whatnot) I noticed that this discoloration jumps from one monitor to the other. So far it seems arbitrary, though most of the time is whichever monitor is connected first.

I never changed any color setting on Windows or the display manager (Nvidia), but just to be sure I reinstalled graphics drivers and set anything to default when possible ... but the issue remains.

I cannot rely on manually adjusting the colors on the monitor because of two reason:

1. from time to time I connect one to my console which makes the discoloration jump again to whatever monitor it feels like.
2. I can never really get full color.

Note:

- The discoloration is not tied to a specific port on the graphics card

I need guidance, this is so weird. I have no idea what is causing such horrid behavior but is driving me nuts.

Comment: change the cable?

Comment: Is there a UPS nearby or something that might be throwing a magnetic field?

Comment: check windows "color management" (view the conttol pannel in small icons) , there are arrays of both color profiles, and user corrections possible , without you having activly changed them even.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek cable is not the problem, as the same monitor with the same cable (and different monitor with different cable) will, at random, have discoloration. I have tried all combinations of physical parts (monitors, cables, ports) so I'm pretty sure is not hardware.

Comment: @Kilisi : No magnetic source nearby. Also, forgot to mention, this is LCD monitor with led backlit, so this is not even a concern

Comment: @Psycogeek : there is not a single color profile there. I don't even have the option to add one, since I'm using default settings.

Comment: sounds like the graphics card might be playing up, can you test with another card? Was there a time when this didn't happen with all the same hardware? Has it gotten worse? Or stayed the same?

Comment: Sadly I don't have another card, but I do have another older monitor, which pretty much does the same thing. This is the first time I try dual screen, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, I'm pretty sure I'm not gonna get an answer so this is the best workaround I found:

1. Set display mode (`Win` + `P`) to use only one of the monitors, so far there is no way of telling which one will work, so try any:

   - Set to PC screen only
   - Set to Secondary only
2. Set it back to Extend
3. Color will again be the same for both screens (if it didn't, try another option for step 1)

Do the above anytime the computer is in a bad mood and decides to mess up with the colors.